# Get value from json of which key is not known (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, json

I have following JSON file:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "msg": "OK",
  "result": {
    "files": {
      "count": 1,
      "pUnJbKzql0f2": {
        "name": "How do I access this",
        "active": "yes"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have to access the value of key `name` in above JSON file. The problem is that the key `pUnJbKzql0f2` keeps changing every time the file is requested. I don't have control over the json file. So how do I access key `name`. Talking about `PHP` we can use `array_keys` or `array_key_exists` function, however I want javascript specific answer for it.

`json['result']['files'][what should I put here]['name']`

```
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Please if someone could post a solution here.

Comment: Object.entries()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to examine the contents of `.result.files`. This can be done using a `for-in` loop where the keys are read.

This snippet illustrates finding the unknown key (and it's value) based on it not being the known key `count`. If the object has more properties you will have to devise a way of excluding those except the one you want.

```js
let requiredKey = "";
let requiredName = "";
const obj = {
  "status": 200,
  "msg": "OK",
  "result": {
    "files": {
      "count": 1,
      "pUnJbKzql0f2": {
        "name": "How do I access this",
        "active": "yes"
      }
    }
  }
}

files = obj.result.files // and object with 2 properties

 for (key in files) {
 
 if (key != "count") {
 
 requiredKey = key;
 requiredName = files[key].name

 } // end if;
      
 } // next key in files

 console.log(`${requiredKey} with name property: ${requiredName}`)
```